# Trigger with table join

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to create a trigger to update stock inventory. My quantity on stock and quantity ordered by the client are on two different tables. How do i join both?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TRIGGER UPDATE_QUANTITY_TRIGGER
AFTER insert ON SALE_ORDER
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
 update product values 
  (:old.product_id,
    :old.product_name,
    :old.description,
    quantity_on_stock-s.quantity,
    :old.minimal_quantity,
    :old.unit_price,
    :old.product_type_id);
  from product, sale_order s
  where product.product_id=s.product_id;
END;
```

OR

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TRIGGER UPDATE_QUANTITY_TRIGGER
AFTER insert ON SALE_ORDER
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
 update product set 
 p.quantity_on_stock= p.quantity_on_stock-s.quantity;
  from product p , sale_order s
  where p.product_id=s.product_id;  
END;
```

The `sale_order` table has columns `sale_no`, `quantity`, and `product_id`.

Comment: That update syntax isn't valid in Oracle, inside a trigger or in plain SQL; you can't join in an update statement (without a subquery). Why do you wan't to join to `sale_order` when you already have the values for the row in the `:old` and `:new` pseudorecords? Trying to maintain a balance like this doesn't really work in a multiuser environment anyway as simultaneous transactions can clash.

Comment: I just want to update the product, is there any work around without using :old ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't join in an update statement. Your second attempt is closer but is still joining, and has no correlation. You also have a stray semicolon. I think you're looking for something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TRIGGER UPDATE_QUANTITY_TRIGGER
AFTER insert ON SALE_ORDER
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
 update product p set 
   p.quantity_on_stock = p.quantity_on_stock - :new.quantity
  where p.product_id = :new.product_id;  
END;
```

This uses the values from the `:new` pseudorecord to both identify the product record to be updated, and to get the quantity to decrement the stock level by. There is no need to join to the triggering table again - which isn't allowed anyway.

You may run into unexpected behaviour or results doing this kind of update in a multiuser environment though.

Comment: I know this is an incredibly old thread but I have a follow-up question:

How could a column in one table be updated by the trigger on another table if the two tables don't have any common columns? I have a table used to join those two tables and, in a typical select statement I would use the join table to associate the other two tables but I cannot figure out how to do so inside the trigger body.

I appreciate any thoughts you may have!

Comment: @Rash8151 - not entirely sure I follow. Your update can use a subquery against the other table. Something like `update t1 set ... where t1.key = (select key from t2 where t2.some_col = :new.some_col)`, or you can use a subquery to get the new value to set , or both - though if both you might want to use an intermediate local variable. Is that the kind of thing you mean? If you not, you need to ask a new question

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was trying to do and your first suggestion worked perfectly. I had experimented with nearly the same but had mixed up a column in my subquery, and this caused it to return an error. Thank you for the help!