# Creating a MySQL trigger to set a boolean value to true if a collection of booleans are true

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I am creating an inventory management app in node.js that uses MySQL as a database. I have a weak entity “rental_item” that holds the items in a particualr rental. The issue is that the rental may not come back all at once so I need a way of marking the “rental_returned” boolean in the rental table true only when all of the “item_returned” entires are true.

Here is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `rental` (
  `rental_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `renter_id` int NOT NULL,
  `date_in` date NOT NULL,
  `date_out` date NOT NULL,
  `sig_path` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `doc_path` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `col_path` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cost` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL,
  `rental_returned` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`rental_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `doc_path` (`doc_path`),
  UNIQUE KEY `col_path` (`col_path`),
  UNIQUE KEY `sig_path` (`sig_path`),
  KEY `renter_key` (`renter_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `renter_key` FOREIGN KEY (`renter_id`) REFERENCES `renter` (`renter_id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `rental_item` (
  `rental_id` int NOT NULL,
  `i_ID` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `item_returned` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `rental_key` (`rental_id`),
  KEY `rental_item_key` (`i_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `rental_item_key` FOREIGN KEY (`i_ID`) REFERENCES `item` (`i_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `rental_key` FOREIGN KEY (`rental_id`) REFERENCES `rental` (`rental_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

I am currently doing this through the mysql2 node.js module and just checking for all the values of a given rental_id. I then found out about triggers and thought this way could be better. I fiddled round with things like this [Trigger with table join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36567588/trigger-with-table-join#), but couldn’t wrap my head around how to get the rental_id of the entry that was updated from rental_item, then check that all entires in rental_item with that id have item_returned = 1, and finally update the rental table to show that all the items/the complete rental has been returned.

I understand that this sould be an update after trigger on rental_item but dont know how to handle the conditionals or loops needed.

Comment: The question you linked to is for Oracle, not MySQL. It has different syntax for accessing the row being updated.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sence was getting very confused between sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NEW.rental_id` to get the ID of the row that was updated.

```
CREATE TRIGGER rental_returned AFTER UPDATE ON rental_item
FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE rental
    SET rental_returned = (
        NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM rental_item
            WHERE rental_id = NEW.rental_id
            AND item_returned = 0))
    WHERE rental_id = NEW.rental_id
```